# how to get day wise dynamically get data using sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I am create one query for the get data last 7 days from the table.now i want to make this query dynamically change days using click on button.then i have change some in the query then after may date is change very well but my data is come current date data. so here i have make small mistake but where i don't know.

This is my query =>

```
SELECT CAST(dateadd(day, T.i, CAST(DATEADD(day,0, GETDATE()) AS Date) AS DateColumn, uf.TotalCount
    FROM (VALUES (-6), (-5), (-4), (-3), (-2), (-1), (0)) AS T(i)
    OUTER APPLY
    (
       SELECT COUNT(UF.InsertDateTime) AS TotalCount
       FROM Users UF               
       WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,UF.InsertDateTime, DATEADD(DAY, T.i, GETDATE())) = 0 and UF.IsLogin = 1
    ) uf
```

this is my data in the table =>

```
UserId | IsLogin | InsertDateTime
-------+---------+---------------------------
 1         1        2017-08-24 16:12:46.713
 2         1        2017-08-23 16:50:55.789
 3         1        2017-08-22 16:12:46.713
 4         1        2017-08-21 16:12:46.713
 5         1        2017-08-20 16:12:46.713
 6         1        2017-08-19 16:12:46.713
 7         1        2017-08-18 16:12:46.713
```

my current o/p=>

```
DateColumn  |  TotalCount
2017-08-18       1
2017-08-19       1
2017-08-20       1
2017-08-21       1
2017-08-22       1
2017-08-23       1
2017-08-24       1
```

This is my o/p is correct. but here in my query i have change day **0** to replace **-6** then i want to change previous 7 days. there previous 7 days is come but in the database data is not availbale but in the result always getting 1 1 1 like..

This my query change days =>

```
 SELECT CAST(dateadd(day, T.i, CAST(DATEADD(day,-6, GETDATE()) AS Date) AS DateColumn, uf.TotalCount
    FROM (VALUES (-6), (-5), (-4), (-3), (-2), (-1), (0)) AS T(i)
    OUTER APPLY
    (
       SELECT COUNT(UF.InsertDateTime) AS TotalCount
       FROM Users UF               
       WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,UF.InsertDateTime, DATEADD(DAY, T.i, GETDATE())) = 0 and UF.IsLogin = 1
    ) uf
```

after change day in query -6 then getting result like this =>

```
 DateColumn  |  TotalCount
2017-08-12       1
2017-08-13       1
2017-08-14       1
2017-08-15       1
2017-08-16       1
2017-08-17       1
2017-08-18       1
```

but here date 12 to 17 in the table data is not available. so i want to correct data from the date wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT dateadd(day, T.i, CAST(DATEADD(day,-6, GETDATE()) AS Date)), uf.TotalCount
    FROM (VALUES (-6), (-5), (-4), (-3), (-2), (-1), (0)) AS T(i)
    OUTER APPLY
    (
       SELECT COUNT(UF.InsertDateTime) AS TotalCount
       FROM user1 UF               
       WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,UF.InsertDateTime, dateadd(day, T.i, CAST(DATEADD(day,-6, GETDATE()) AS Date))) = 0 and UF.IsLogin = 1
    ) uf
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? If 6 days before date exist in users table then only count should 1??

Comment: hello i need some take hint from your side so can you please help me? i get facing some problem with this query in my table 1+ million data is store so that time this query take more time for the get data so how can improve this query can you please give me some idea.

Comment: Your inner query depend on outer month calculation so obviously it will take time so better I suggest try something which will reduce every time month calculation.